# Transfering note to own column by row in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a very large excel file with hundreds of notes on different cells. I would like to extract the notes contents of each row and put them in their own column. For example if I had 3 notes in row 1, the text from those comments would be put in say U1. And if 4 comments were in row 2 those 4 comments would be in U2, and so one. I am using VBA to do this so far but am having trouble getting them to separate by row.

```
Sub CopyCommentsToCol()
Dim i As Integer
i = 2
Dim Rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim commrange As Range
Dim curwks As Worksheet

Set Rng = Range("A2:A5") 'Test Range for now
Set curwks = ActiveSheet

On Error Resume Next
  Set commrange = curwks.Cells _
      .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments)
On Error GoTo 0


On Error Resume Next
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  Err.Clear
End If

For Each row In Rng.Rows
    For Each cell In commrange 'Application.ActiveCell.Comment
        If cell.Comment <> Empty Then
            Range("$U$" & i) = Range("$U$" & i).Text & cell.Comment.Text 
        End If

    Next cell
    i = i + 1
Next row
End Sub
```

This vba code currently puts all of the notes in the test range i specified. Not just the notes in their own row. I understand my error here, the inner for loop is going through the entire sheet. I just don't know how to fix this problem.

**EDIT**

```
For Each row In Rng.Rows
    Set commrange = row.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments)
    For Each cell In commrange
        If cell.Comment <> Empty Then
            Range("$U$" & i) = Range("$U$" & i).Text & cell.Comment.Text
        End If
    Next cell
    i = i + 1
Next row
```

Comment: Copy and then Paste Transpose?

Comment: How would you copy just the comments in one row

Comment: Sorry, it's late where I am, I read cells when I should have read comments. If you posted the VBA you've attempted so far maybe it'll help. Try recording a macro when interacting with comments and look at the code that is generated.

Comment: I updated the post with my vba code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Rows` collection. Something like

```
For Each row In yourRange.Rows
    'collect comments
Next row
```

UPDATE:

As the first idea didn't work, you can check `cell.Row` and use it when adding text in cell.

```
Sub CopyCommentsToCol()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim commrange As Range
Dim curwks As Worksheet

Set Rng = Range("A2:A5") 'Test Range for now
Set curwks = ActiveSheet

On Error Resume Next
  Set commrange = curwks.Cells _
      .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments)
On Error GoTo 0


On Error Resume Next
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  Err.Clear
End If

For Each cell In commrange 'Application.ActiveCell.Comment
    If cell.Comment <> Empty Then
        Range("$U$" & cell.Row) = Range("$U$" & cell.Row).Text & cell.Comment.Text 
    End If

Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: I have done that already. The problem is separating the comments collected by row. As you can see from the updated post

Comment: You should put whole collecting part in this loop, especially `Set commrange = row.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments)`. I don't have access to Excel ATM, so I can't test it unfortunately.

Comment: Can you elaborate more. Setting commrange to 
    row.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments) doesnt change anything, also setting commrage within the loop does not solve the problem.

Comment: @ReesMcDevitt the idea is to first take only one row, and then take comments. It will give you comments from this row only. Right now, you are taking all comments from worksheet and can't separate them.

Comment: I posted an edit of what I think you are saying and it still causes the same error.

Comment: @ReesMcDevitt So, if this is not working, you should be able to check `cell.Row` just after `cell.Comment <> Empty` and add it to corresponding row. In that way you don't need row loop.

Comment: Yup that works, thanks so much, I was trying that and I forgot to change commrange to the entire worksheet again.